# Irrational Roots To Third-Degree Polynomial Equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do I find irrational roots to a third-degree polynomial equation? I have already used up all my p/q options so there are no rational roots. I don't think I can use the quadratic formula because it is in the third-degree.

Equation: $x^3 -8x^2 - 200 = 0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could notice that $x=10$ is a root, then find the remaining quadratic using long division and see if that has irrational roots (hint irrational roots are still real ones).

Comment: Oh thanks! I messed up on my calculations on 10.

Answer (score 0):

[Newton's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) can be used to find an arbitrarily accurate solution to $x^3-8x^2-200=0$.

Answer (score 0):

The first test, if the coefficients are rationals, is the [rational root test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem). This gives you one rational root, i.e., $x=10$. Now divide $x^3-8x^2-200$ by $x-10$. This gives you are quadratic with complex roots. Also, remember that [WolframAlpha is your friend](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E3-8%2ax%5E2-200).